# I have a sql dump I'm trying to import but I get a syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

### Error

#### Static analysis:

2 errors were found during analysis.

1. Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "phpMyAdmin" at position 0)
2. Unrecognized statement type. (near "SQL" at position 11)

#### SQL query:

```
phpMyAdmin SQL Dump -- version 4.5.1 -- http://www.phpmyadmin.net -- -- Host: 127.0.0.1 -- Generation Time: Apr 12, 2017 at 04:16 AM -- Server version: 10.1.13-MariaDB -- PHP Version: 5.6.23 SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO"
```

#### MySQL said: Documentation

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
 -- version 4.5.1
 -- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
 --
 -- Host: 12' at line 1
```

Comment: Are there some newlines missing from what you pasted?

Comment: i pasted the error i got when trying to import the sql file

Answer (score 1):

fixed by:

Skip this number of queries (for SQL) starting from the first one:  1 (instead of 0)

Answer (score 0):

[`--` indicates a comment in SQL](https://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_comments.asp). I imagine your dump was supposed to look like this with everything up to `SET SQL_MODE ...` being a comment.

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.5.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net --
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Apr 12, 2017 at 04:16 AM
-- Server version: 10.1.13-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 5.6.23

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO"
```

Comment: -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.5.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Apr 12, 2017 at 04:16 AM
-- Server version: 10.1.13-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 5.6.23

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

Comment: @zCYANIDEz Pasting code in a comment just results in a jumble. And I see there's now a leading `--` that isn't in the original. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53677610/edit) with the right code and use the "Code Sample" formatting button on it, the `{}` button. Then there will be less confusion and we can help you out.